# ¿cómo separar palabras de una cadena en Python?

Tags: python, bucle-for, while

queria saber si me pueden ayudar, recien estoy empezando en programacion y en tres dias tengo examen y ando medio perdido. Tengo que realizar este programa y me cuesta empezar, SOLO NOS DEJAN USAR `FOR`, `WHILE`, `IF`, `ELSE`, `LEN()`, `STR` Y NADA MAS, no se si me podrían ayudar

Hacer un programa que pida el ingreso de una frase y de como salida una nueva frase
donde en cada palabra estarán primeros sus consonantes, luego sus vocales y por último un número aleatorio.

Especificaciones:

1. Las consonantes (o caracteres especiales) deberán verse en minúsculas y en el orden en que aparecen en la palabra.
2. Las vocales deberán estar en mayúsculas y en el orden inverso en que aparecen en cada palabra de la frase.
3. Los espacios se reemplazarán con un número aleatorio entre 10 y 99 seguido por un espacio en blanco.

Ejemplo:

```
frase = “caracoles desafiantes e irrespetuosos!”
salida = “crclsEOAA41 dsfntsEAIAE98 E91 rrsptss!OOUEEI54”
```

Comment: Bienvenido marcos cardozo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: También es importante que entiendas, que las tareas académicas, son bien recibidas siempre que agregues lo que que hayas intentado hasta el momento y las dificultades con las que te hayas encontrado. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `# coding=utf-8` es por si deseas utilizar el alfabeto español o las tildes en las letras `aáAÁeéEÉiíIÍoóOÓuúUÚ`.

```
    # coding=utf-8
    import random
    frase="caracoles desafiantes e irrespetuosos! "
    nueva_frase=""
    consonantes=""
    vocales=""
    espacio=""
    palabra=""
    convinaciones='aáAÁeéEÉiíIÍoóOÓuúUÚ'
    i=0
    for f in frase:
        i+=1
        if (f==" " or i==len(frase)) :
            palabra=palabra+f
            for x in palabra:
                if x in convinaciones:
                        vocales=x.upper()+vocales 
                elif x==" ":
                    espacio=str(random.randint(10, 99))+ " "
                else:
                    consonantes=consonantes+x.lower()
            nueva_frase=nueva_frase+(consonantes+vocales+espacio)
            consonantes=""
            vocales=""
            espacio=""  
            palabra=""  
        else:
            palabra=palabra+f


    print(nueva_frase)
```

Resultado:

```
crclsEOAA44 dsfntsEAIAE23 E27 rrsptss!OOUEEI80
```

Answer (score 0):

Pueden haber diversas vias para llegar al resultado buscado, con la frase “caracoles desafiantes e irrespetuosos!”. Se me ocurre que pudieras probar con el siguiente codigo:

```
from random import randrange

mi_frase = ("caracoles desafiantes e irrespetuosos!") # Frase de entrada
mi_salida = ("crclsEOAAxx dsfntsEAIAExx Exx rrsptss!OOUEEIxx" ) # Salida buscada

cadena1 = ("caracoles")
cadena2 = ("desafiantes")
cadena3 = ("e")
cadena4 = ("irrespetuosos!")

vocales = "a","e","i","o","u"

nueva_cadena1 = ""
nueva_cadena2 = ""
nueva_cadena3 = ""
nueva_cadena4 = ""

for letra in cadena1:
        if not(letra.lower() in vocales):
            nueva_cadena1 += letra

for letra in cadena2:
        if not(letra.lower() in vocales):
            nueva_cadena2 += letra    

for letra in cadena3:
        if not(letra.lower() in vocales):
            nueva_cadena3 += letra

for letra in cadena4:
        if not(letra.lower() in vocales):
            nueva_cadena4 += letra 

consonantes = "b", "c", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",\
 "ñ", "p", "q", "r","s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "!"

nueva_cadena_1 = ""
nueva_cadena_2 = ""
nueva_cadena_3 = ""
nueva_cadena_4 = ""    

for letra in cadena1:
        if not(letra.lower() in consonantes):
            nueva_cadena_1 += letra

for letra in cadena2:
        if not(letra.lower() in consonantes):
            nueva_cadena_2 += letra

for letra in cadena3:
        if not(letra.lower() in consonantes):
            nueva_cadena_3 += letra

for letra in cadena4:
        if not(letra.lower() in consonantes):
            nueva_cadena_4 += letra

cadena_a = nueva_cadena1 + nueva_cadena_1.upper()[::-1] + str(randrange(10,99))
cadena_b = nueva_cadena2 + nueva_cadena_2.upper()[::-1] + str(randrange(10,99))
cadena_c = nueva_cadena3 + nueva_cadena_3.upper()[::-1] + str(randrange(10,99))
cadena_d = nueva_cadena4 + nueva_cadena_4.upper()[::-1] + str(randrange(10,99))

print(cadena_a + " " + cadena_b + " " + cadena_c + " " + cadena_d + " ")
```